VSCode: Regex to 'Replace in Files' multiple matches after a specific word
I have a bunch of files which have a specific line in which I need to do some find & replace (via VSCode function 'Replace in Files' (Ctrl+Shift+H)).
Imagine the following (as-is):
---
Created at: 2017-03-09
Last updated at: 2017-03-09
tags: #On-going #Future_Fixes
---

I would need the following (to-be):
---
Created at: 2017-03-09
Last updated at: 2017-03-09
tags:
  - On-going
  - Future_Fixes
---

Basically I need, in a list of files, to have in every line that starts with tags: string, to replace all  # by \\n  - .
Find: (?<=tags:)\s#+
Replace by: \n  - 
What I get is:
---
Created at: 2017-03-09
Last updated at: 2017-03-09
tags:
  - On-going #Future_Fixes
---

So it seems to be running only on the first instance, but not for the following terms I want to match.
Can anyone share any insights that may help achieve the above?
Thanks in advance.

If I get it right, you've already figured out the regex for the strings to be replaced. What language do you want to write the script in?

Actually I would like to understand if I can use VSCode to do this for all the files at once (via VSCode function 'Replace in Files' (Ctrl+Shift+H).

It is very tricky to do this with a lookbehind in vscode's search across files because, as you know, it doesn't support non-fixed length lookbehinds.  Some answers will just suggest that you run a find/replace multiple times changing one match at a time until you have changed them all.  If you wanted to do that try this:
find:     (?<=tags:)(.*)\s#
replace:  $1\n  - 
and keep running the search and replace all until it doesn't find anything anymore.  If you have 2 items in the tags you would have to run this twice.
But, vscode does support non-fixed length lookaheads.  So if your tags: line is always followed by the --- line then you can do this:
#(?=.*\n---)

and replace as you had: \n - .
It is just looking for #'s with a --- on the next line.  You only have to run this once no matter how many tags items there are.
See Regex101 demo.

Unfortunately this does not work properly in 'Find/Replace in Files' (Ctrl+Shift+F/H), but only in regular 'Find/Replace' (Ctrl+F/H) inside a single file.
I get error 'Regex parse error: lookbehind assertion is not fixed Iength'.
I've read that the Regex engine used in these commands is not the same, so I wonder again if this is possible in VSCode 'Find/Replace in Files' (Ctrl+Shift+F/H)

@user5923286 I missed that, but I edited the answer which does now work in the search across files view.  This assumes that your next line is --- after the tags:... line.  Please advise if that is not the case.
